# How to sampleOn signal and keep the sampled value in Elm?

Tags: elm, elm-signal

Consider a model:

```elm
model : Signal Model
```

and the following 2 signals:

```elm
clickPosition = Mouse.position
  |> Signal.sampleOn Mouse.clicks
```

and:

```elm
dimensions = Window.dimensions
```

I'd like to get the following `desiredSignal`:

```
            (0,0)       (30,20)               (60,70)
clickPosition +------------+---------------------+---------

              M0   M1                  M2     M3
        model +----+-------------------+------+------------

          (600,800)         (400,300)  (200,800)
   dimensions +-----------------+----------+---------------

              D1           D2                    D3
desiredSignal +------------+---------------------+---------


where:

  D1 = ((0,0), M0, (600,800))
  D2 = ((30,20), M1, (600,800))
  D3 = ((60,70), M3, (200,800))
```

i.e. I'd like to sampleOn `clickPosition`, but keep the sampled value.

How could I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your `desiredSignal` is the latest value of the three signals, tupled, but only changing on a change from the `clickPosition` signal. You can do this by first combining them, and then sampling on the `clickPosition` signal:

```
desiredSignal =
  Signal.map3 (,,) clickPosition model dimensions
  |> Signal.sampleOn clickPosition
```

Comment: Aha! For some reason, I thought that if I sampleOn `clickPosition` then it shouldn't be involved in the mapping. Makes perfect sense now, Thanks!